# Mingw compiling error on Linux with a program made on Windows

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks

I've recently migrated from Windows 7 to Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) and want to compile a C program that I made. The program worked perfectly under Codeblocks 12.11 using GNU GCC compiler's basic settings. When compiling under linux under Codeblocks 13.12 using GNU GCC compiler's basic settings, I get the following error messages:

> undefined reference to __mingw_vprintf
>   undefined reference to __chstk.ms
>   undefined reference to _fopen

... and so on with `fscanf`, `malloc`, etc...

I'm new to Linux and I am not used to C coding, or even programming in general. Does someone have an idea about what's going on?

Comment: You're having a problem with the linker.  Maybe you need to adjust your projects dependencies (includes) list.

Comment: As @FiddlingBits noted, you're missing some linker dependencies. I'm not sure how you have C::B configured, but it looks like you're trying to use a MinGW compiler. Have you switched your project's compiler configuration to use your platform's GNU C compiler instead of the MinGW one? It might be a project-specific setting instead of a global C::B setting since it is still looking for MinGW stuff and you migrated from Windows to Linux.

Comment: It is odd that you get an error about `__mingw_vprintf`.  Does your program specifically call this function?  Or are you trying to link object files or libraries which you compiled under Windows? (as opposed to what you should be doing, which is fully rebuilding all binaries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have three separate problem going on here.

(1) for _fopen, Microsoft has a nasty habit of renaming all the POSIX functions so they start with an underscore, while your Linux distribution is looking for the standard POSIX name, i.e. fopen.  Welcome to the wonderfully frustrating world of cross-platform development :).  On solution would be to add something along these lines:

```
#ifdef __WIN32
    #define fopen _fopen
#endif
```

This in effect says, if compiling on a windows machine (which typically has __WIN32 defined as a preprocessor define; and if it is not you can always make sure that it is) replace every occurrence of `fopen` with `_fopen`.  The preprocessor will do this for you.

(2) for __mingw_vprintf, I've never seen this function but from the name I would surmise that it is an implementation of vprintf specific to mingw.  I personally would rewrite my code to stick with the standard C function `vprintf`.  You can read the manual page for vprintf [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vprintf/); and the MSDN information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zf95wk0.aspx).  Again notice that many of the Microsoft provide functions have an underscore prepended to the name.  You can do something like what you did in case (1) above.

N.B. Actually if I were to rewrite the program I would use C++ IO-streams, but I am sticking to a pure C answers.

(3) for __chstk.ms, again I've never seen this function.  My suspicion is that it is something inserted into your code to perform stack checking to help prevent stack-based exploits.  To the best of my knowledge there is no way you are going to get that to work on a Linux machine.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to vote up, I will do so whenever possible. Thanks a lot ! :)